# How to save the password input given by the user in a shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, passwords

I have the `shiny` app below in which when a password given a database connection is enabled. This connenction is enabled via a big number of passwords which are known only from the database admin. So every time the user gives a wrong password a message is displayed. What I would like to achieve is find a way (probably a pop-up message) that will give the user the ability to save this password for later use so he will not have to enter it every time. Is this a javascript work?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(odbc)
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px"
)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px"
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      passwordInput("pwd",label = "",value = "",width = "100%" ),
      actionButton('button', "Continue"),
      uiOutput("error")
    )
    
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    con <- try( dbConnect( odbc(),
                           driver   = "SQL Server",
                           database = "databasename",
                           server   = svr,
                           port     = 1433,
                           UID      = "uid",
                           PWD      = input$pwd))
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      if( class(con) != "try-error" ) {
        # OK code
      }
      else{
        output$error<-renderUI({
          "Please re-enter database browser password"
        })
      }
      
      
      
    })
  }
  )
)
```

Comment: This sounds like the job of a password manager, a program that should be made with great care. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, have you looked at tagging your input so that modern browsers and password managers are able to address it? If you still want to proceed, you can look at ways to store a cookie or token client-side, and when the token is found authentication is made.

Comment: I would prefer something like a workaround